# pd.ExcelWriter, append datetime but got: Unknown or unsupported datetime type

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I'm making a tool to import a .txt file and export it as a .xslx file using pd.ExcelWriter. For import I use `pd.read_csv` which works fine. Export the dataframe as a .xslx works also fine except that the datetimes are not recognized by excel:

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(ex_name,sep=';',skip_blank_lines=False,index_col=False,header=None,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_numbers': True},
                        datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')
    
csv_file.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False,header=False)
writer.save()
```

So I added a few lines before the writer.save() to change the format:

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
formatdict = {'num_format':'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm'}
fmt = workbook.add_format(formatdict)

worksheet.write_datetime('C6:C{0}'.format(int(len(date_export)+5)),date_export),fmt)
```

Where `csv_file` is the imported .txt file, `date_export` the date serie I tried to overwrite. But I got an typeerror: `Unknown or unsupported datetime type`

I also tried to append a new date range created with `pd.date_range`:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(start=date_export[0], periods=len(date_export),
                              freq='D', normalize=True)
```

With `dtype='datetime64[ns]` but I got the same error.

So exporting using `pd.ExcelWriter` works (while using the first code block only) but get excel recognize the datetime doesn't work due to the error in the python console.

**FULL ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\txt_to_excel.py", line 399, in <module>
    worksheet.write_datetime('C6:C{0}'.format(int(len(daterange)+5)),daterange)#,fmt)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 69, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 770, in write_datetime
    return self._write_datetime(row, col, date, cell_format)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 784, in _write_datetime
    number = self._convert_date_time(date)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 3892, in _convert_date_time
    self.remove_timezone)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\utility.py", line 677, in datetime_to_excel_datetime
    raise TypeError("Unknown or unsupported datetime type")

TypeError: Unknown or unsupported datetime type
```

**FIRST 10 LINES INPUT FILE**

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;
LOCATION;FILTER NR;X COORD;Y COORD;SURFACE LEV (m-ref);TOP FILTER (m-ref);BOTTOM FILTER (m-ref);MEAS POINT LEV (m-ref);SED SUMP LENGTH (m);START DATE;
pb 1-1;1;1;1;1;1;1;;;2006-08-17 00:00:00

LOCATION;FILTER NR;DATE;VALUE (m-ref)
pb 1-1;1;2006-08-17 00:00:00;40.384
pb 1-1;1;2006-08-18 00:00:00;40.337
pb 1-1;1;2006-08-19 00:00:00;40.296
pb 1-1;1;2006-08-20 00:00:00;40.321
pb 1-1;1;2006-08-21 00:00:00;40.358000000000004
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Is perfect except for the fact that the datetime isn't recognized.
[image]

Comment: Can you please give an example of your input txt file? Also, please provide the code in which you use pd.read_csv().

Comment: Also can you add the full type error and not just a summary.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added the information.

Comment: Does it show the same error if you include the parameters parse_dates=[2], infer_datetime_format=True in pd.read_csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a variety of different Pandas `parse_dates` and similar options but I couldn't get them to work with the format of your input data. Perhaps someone else will figure that out and post a working example.

As an alternative here is a version that extends the default Xlsxwriter `worksheet.write()` method to convert date-like strings to Excel dates on the fly.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

ex_name = 'so63718752.txt'

csv_file = pd.read_csv(ex_name, sep=';', skip_blank_lines=False,
                       index_col=False, header=None,
                       usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_numbers': True},
                        datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')

csv_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet object used by Pandas.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Make the date columns wider for clarity in this example.
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 12, None)
worksheet.set_column(9, 9, 12, None)

# Create a date format to use in Excel.
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'})


# Create a function that changes the worksheet write() method so
# that strings are evaluated into dates or just handled normally.
def string_to_date(worksheet, row, col, cell, cell_format=None):
    try:
        # Try convert the cell string to a date.
        date_time = datetime.strptime(cell, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # If it works then write it as an Excel date.
        return worksheet.write_datetime(row, col, date_time, date_format)
    except:
        # If it doesn't work then return control to the calling write() method.
        return None

# Add the write() handler/callback to the worksheet.
worksheet.add_write_handler(str, string_to_date)

# Write the file again. This is inefficient but, I think, unavoidable.
csv_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False)

writer.save()
```

Output (note that the data type is "Date" in Excel):

[image]

See [Writing user defined types](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html#writing-user-defined-types) in the XlsxWriter docs for an explanation of how this works.

This is somewhat on the advanced end of XlsxWriter, and any working Pandas example would probably be complex as well. A better and simpler approach would probably be to just read the data using csv.py and convert it an Excel file using XlsxWriter directly.

Comment: Thanks for your afford, great! I agree it is a work around but that is more than fine after struggling for a week ;-)